# Does an ASP.NET HttpHandler ever timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have implemented an ASP.NET http handler. It appears to me that there is no way to set a timeout e.g. if the handler has been running for over X seconds dont serve the result.

Am I correct here or is there a way to achieve a timeout for an ashx handler?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ASP.Net has a built in timeout that will cause it to kill a connection exceeding the configured limits.

[The default is 110 seconds.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout.aspx)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110">        
</system.web>
```

However, this is disabled when compiled in DEBUG mode.

```
<!-- Execution Timeout Will Not Be Enforced -->
<compilation debug="true" />
```

If you need to set an execution timeout for a specific handler, then you can always create a location specifically for that handler, and set the timeout there.

```
<location path="MyHandler.ashx">
  <system.web>
    <!-- Set execution timeout to 10 minutes -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```